# Is this ad wrong? Or, is my understanding wrong (quite possible)

Tags: word-choice

This is an ad for Cathay Pacific posted in downtown Boston. 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/31789321@N03/16882394887/

It reads: 
波士頓至香港
不停站
每周四班

I am surprised by two things in this ad copy that I think might be wrong.  First, shouldn't "至" be "到"?  Second, since this ad uses traditional characters (as seen up top in the part I didn't get in the photo), shouldn't "周" be "週"?

Thanks in advance for any help and clarity.

-Nawen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 至 and 到 mean `to`, but 至 is often used in written Chinese, so it's not a mistake, 周 and 週 are both correct in traditional Chinese, mean week, but we don't use 週 in Simple Chinese, even everyone can understand it

Comment: OK, thank you Jonathan. I appreciate this!

Comment: Glad it helped!